# Почему сердце уходит в пятки?

Tags: фразеология

"Сердце ушло в пятки" - так говорят об очень сильном испуге. Но почему именно в пятки? Когда человек пугается, сердце начинает биться очень сильно - это факт. Может ощущаться пульсация где-нибудь в животе или возникать какие-то еще неприятные эффекты. Но не знаю, чтобы сердцебиение вдруг начало ощущаться в ногах (может, мне просто не доводилось пугаться настолько сильно?).
Одним словом, почему сердце уходит в пятки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сердце уходит в пятки из-за нашей полезной привычки ходить босиком. К примеру, у англичан сердце опускается в ботинки, у немцев - падает в брюки. В общем, оно как бы обрывается и падает вниз.

Кроме того, при испуге у человека появляются различные "прохладные" ощущения:  мороз по коже дерет,   кровь в жилах леденеет,  мурашки ползают и бегают по коже, спине и всему телу. Ну и волосы иногда шевелятся на голове.

А здесь указано место на пятках, куда оно падает

http://vivasan-sibir.ru/articles/massazh/serdtse-i-pochki-ushli-v-pyatki/

А это примеры

http://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/676/ДУША_В_ПЯТКИ_УХОДИТ

Comment: Интересная информация об англичанах и немцах.

Answer (score 1):

Мммм....

Чот как-то неубедительно все.
Мне кажется, все проще. Во-первых, сдаётся мне, в пятки уходит прежде всего *душа*, сердце - уже вторично. 
Тому есть два объяснения. Примитивное - хочется бежать (так что пятки сверкают).  
И более продвинутое. 
При сильном испуге возникает ощущение "проваливающихся" внутренностей. 
Именно так описывают это состояние очень многие пережившие.
Вроде бы связано с расслаблением плоских мышц брюшной полости.

Ну а *пятки* - самая нижняя точка, куда "душа" может опуститься.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, кто уже будет читать комментарии мои, но скажу - я испытала на себе, что такое "сердце ушло в пятки". У меня потерялся ребенок, и, когда я увидела медленно отъезжавшую машину и в голову пришли не самые лучшие мысли, в пятках четко начал отбиваться пульс. Ни холодок, ни мороз, ничего другого, а четкая пульсация в пятках. Так что такое бывает. А масик мой побежал с собакой на ферму. :))

Comment: "Не знаю, кто уже будет читать комментарии мои" === Прочитал с интересом и исправил пунктуацию.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, это самое надежное место, чтобы переждать неприятности)))

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое было при сильном испуге. Ощущение, что внутренние органы - сердце и прочее - опускаются вниз. Какая-то волна проходит, как будто падаешь в пропасть: ладони, стопы в пот бросает.